# How To add or subtract two numbers from an interval that theree result must be in same interval

Tags: summation

I have a question. I'm searching for two methods that

1) Sum of two random numbers from an Intervals must be on that interval.

2) subtract of two random numbers from an Intervals must be on the interval.

For example : Interval :[2,6]
if randomly select 5.6 and 4 then 5.6 and 4 is not in the [2,6]. I need that the sum is in the interval.

OR

If we select randomly 2 and 6 then 2-6=-4 and (-4) is not in the interval [2,6].

Can anyone help me please ?

Great thanks

Comment: So you are only considering ranges $[a,b]$ such that $b-a \ge a$, which is to say that $b\ge 2a$.  Are you asking for a probability distribution that matches the two conditions?

Comment: Thanks , NO distribution , really I'm searching for a method that convert the result in the interval [a,b], either for summation or for subtract.
And the interval can be every thing. please help . Thanks

Comment: I don't think that this should be closed as "unclear what your asking". The OP is clearly willing to interact! If you are not sure what the question is, then ask for a clarification about the specific point which is unclear! If there is no response *then* close it.